# svn dump file : Node-copyfrom-rev

Tags: svn

I am a bit confused about this. I have a svn dump file that I have filtered (therefore, I am not sure if it is still a valid dump file).

Is it possible to have a `Node-copyfrom-rev` in the header from a revision where the file was not modified? Or does the Node-copyfrom-rev always point to where the node was last modified?

For instance, `file1` was created in `revision 1` but it was moved to `folder2` in `revision 6`. Can `file1` have a copyfrom path in `revision 6` from `revision` say `5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the field `Node-copyfrom-rev` can point to revisions, in which the file `Node-copyfrom-path` has not been changed - and it usually does. Here is an example:

If have added the file `foo` in rev 1 and it hasn't been changed in rev 2. Now I execute the following command lines:

```
svn cp foo@1 bar
svn cp foo@2 baz
svn commit
```

Using `svnrdump dump`, I get the following output:

```
Node-path: bar
Node-copyfrom-rev: 1
Node-copyfrom-path: foo

Node-path: baz
Node-copyfrom-rev: 2
Node-copyfrom-path: foo
```